# How can I show only n chars in varchar column in Access or SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

Let's say I have this `varchar` column "hello world this is my name"

and I want to show with a `select field1 from table` only the first word which is "hello"

Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Access? They don't use exactly the same syntax and it might affect the answer.

Comment: you want to fetch only the first word in the field to your C# application. Select statement will select the whole field, but its upto you on how much you want to fetch to your client application. Is this what you want?

Comment: After taking another look at your tags, I'm not sure what you're asking. You tagged C#, sql-server, and Access. What are you asking?

Comment: I'm using access but since I don't know if is possible I can use sqlserver too. My app is in c#, but the code I need is access/sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access has the `LEFT()` function as well.

To show the first word from each column (no matter how long it is) you can use `INSTR()` to find the first blank, and take only the part left of that with the `LEFT()` function:

```
SELECT LEFT(field1, INSTR(1, field1, " ") - 1) AS YourSubString
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LEFT()` function in SQL server (not sure about Access and you've tagged both):

```
SELECT    LEFT(field1, 5) AS [YourSubString]
FROM      [YourTable]
```